# Getting in Insert query : Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to insert data using below query -

```
INSERT INTO table (id,code, responses_bitstring, responses_double, responses_text) VALUES('1', '1',null, '{1,5,6,9}',null);
```

using -

```
ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
```

While execution I am getting below error -

```
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

I am aware that the error is because of '{1,5,6,9}' this which starts the search for the particular index. Is there any way I can execute the same query?

Comment: How does your `table` look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski 
Table - `id uuid NOT NULL, code varchar(100),responses_bitstring varbit,responses_double double precision [],responses_text varchar [], PRIMARY KEY(id)`